# R: there is no package called "shiny"?

Tags: r, shiny

i can try to install the package get in error message below

```
library(shiny)
Error in library(shiny): there is no package called "shiny" .
```

R-studio software update is available can i update the R-studio software.

current version of R-studio software: V1.1.442

Comment: You need to install the shiny package. Run `install.packages("shiny")`

Answer (score 1):

As phil said, `install.packages("shiny")`  should work. But for future reference this is how to do it manually.

[How to add packages manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEs8U.png)

By clicking 'install' and searching on the CRAN the package name will show up in a search column, some packages don't exist on CRAN and must be installed manually through other means (I *think* some packages not updated to latest version of R can be used this way but not 100% sure).

`install.packages("shiny")` installs the packages from CRAN.

`library("shiny")` loads the package from your currently installed packages... it won't show if you haven't installed it.

Comment: yes..starts the install and looks like its working but ends with this error:

Comment: ERROR: dependency 'fastmap' is not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "<C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\library>" C:\Users\n1003490\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Rtmp0OU3xH/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.5.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
  ‘C:\Users\n1003490\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Rtmp0OU3xH\downloaded_packages’

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure, it's been a while and I rarely log into stack exchange but did you manage to figure it out?